# paypal send multiple items?

Tags: php, arrays, paypal

dear friends this is my array to send multiple items on paypal.

```
Array
(
    [item_name1] => this is the testing job
    [item_number1] => 2433
    [amount1] => 40
    [item_name2] => testing job 2
    [item_number2] => 2435
    [amount2] => 40
    [item_name3] => testing job 3
    [item_number3] => 2437
    [amount3] => 40
    [item_name4] => testing job 4
    [item_number4] => 2439
    [amount4] => 40
    [item_name5] => testing job 5
    [item_number5] => 2441
    [amount5] => 40
    [item_name6] => testing job 6
    [item_number6] => 2443
    [amount6] => 40
    [business] => mysend@mydoma.com
    [currency_code] => USD
    [cbt] => Continue to testing code
    [return] => http://mydomain.com/order/4456/?_wpnonce=de449cd303
    [cancel_return] => http://mydomain.com/order/4456/?cancel=1
    [noshipping] => 1
    [no_note] => 1
    [rm] => 0
    [charset] => utf-8
    [cmd] => _xclick
)
```

this array is not working. then i searching on google i found to item_name_1 like array

```
Array
(
    [item_name_1] => this is the testing job
    [item_number_1] => 2433
    [amount_1] => 40
    [item_name_2] => testing job 2
    [item_number_2] => 2435
    [amount_2] => 40
    [item_name_3] => testing job 3
    [item_number_3] => 2437
    [amount_3] => 40
    [item_name_4] => testing job 4
    [item_number_4] => 2439
    [amount_4] => 40
    [item_name_5] => testing job 5
    [item_number_5] => 2441
    [amount_5] => 40
    [item_name_6] => testing job 6
    [item_number_6] => 2443
    [amount_6] => 40
    [business] => mysend@mydoma.com
    [currency_code] => USD
    [cbt] => Continue to testing code
    [return] => http://mydomain.com/order/4456/?_wpnonce=de449cd303
    [cancel_return] => http://mydomain.com/order/4456/?cancel=1
    [noshipping] => 1
    [no_note] => 1
    [rm] => 0
    [charset] => utf-8
    [cmd] => _xclick
)
```

but this array i passed on paypal but the paypal is not showing any item please help.

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all xclick type is used for sending instant payment to paypal for multiple product you have to use cart

```
Array
(
[item_name_1] => this is the testing job
[item_number_1] => 2433
[amount_1] => 40
[item_name_2] => testing job 2
[item_number_2] => 2435
[amount_2] => 40
[item_name_3] => testing job 3
[item_number_3] => 2437
[amount_3] => 40
[item_name_4] => testing job 4
[item_number_4] => 2439
[amount_4] => 40
[item_name_5] => testing job 5
[item_number_5] => 2441
[amount_5] => 40
[item_name_6] => testing job 6
[item_number_6] => 2443
[amount_6] => 40
[business] => mysend@mydoma.com
[currency_code] => USD
[cbt] => Continue to testing code
[return] => http://mydomain.com/order/4456/?_wpnonce=de449cd303
[cancel_return] => http://mydomain.com/order/4456/?cancel=1
[noshipping] => 1
[no_note] => 1
[rm] => 0
[charset] => utf-8
[cmd] => _cart
[upload] => 1
)
```

Use this array it will help you